When do (or don't) residue fields generate the derived category of a ring?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $D(R)$ its derived category of unbounded chain complexes. I'm interested in when the residue fields $k(\mathfrak{p}) = \mathrm{Frac}(R/\frak p)$ for $\mathfrak p \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ generate (or don't generate!) $D(R)$ as a localizing subcategory. In other words, when do/don't we have
$$
D(R) = \mathrm{Loc}(k(\mathfrak p)\mid \mathfrak p \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)) 
$$
This is equivalent to the claim that
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_{D(R)}(k(\mathfrak p),E) = 0 \text{ for all } \mathfrak p \in \mathrm{Spec}(R) \implies E = 0. 
$$

If $R$ is noetherian, the residue fields always generate, for example by Neeman's work.
Neeman has also given an example of a non-noetherian ring $R$ where $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is a point, and for which the residue fields don't generate. Thus, there doesn't seem to be a good topological condition on $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ which implies that the residue fields generate.
There are other known examples where residue fields do not generate. For example, if $R$ is an absolutely-flat ring that is not semi-artinian, then this fails by Theorem 4.7 of Stevenson's work.

Here is an example where I do not know the answer either way: take $R = k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$. I suspect that the residue fields do not generate in this case. I even have a candidate that might not be built from residue fields: let $I = (x_1^2,x_2^3,\ldots)$ and consider the injective hull $E(R/I)$. By Example 9.1 here this is an indecomposable injective which is not of the form $E(R/\mathfrak p)$ for any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$. If one could show that any non-zero morphism $f \colon k(\mathfrak p) \to E(R/I)$ must be injective, then there are in fact no non-zero morphisms. But I do not know if this injectivity must hold.

The ideal example would be to find a ring $R$ generated by residue fields, whose spectrum does not satisfy a topological property we call weakly noetherian (or to show that finding such an $R$ is not possible). This is described a little more in this answer, but this means that the Hochster dual of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ satisfies the $T_D$-separation axiom (each of its points is locally closed). For example, the infinite polynoimal ring considered above is an example of a ring whose spectrum is not weakly noetherian. Every noetherian ring has weakly notherian spectrum, but there are also other examples (for example, $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is weakly noetherian if $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is Hochster scattered).

To summarise:

Are there any interesting classes of rings for which we can say generation by residue fields holds, or doesn't hold?
Can we say anything in the case that $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is not weakly noetherian, for example, for the infinite polynomial ring mentioned in the question.


It is confusing to me to refer to residue fields at non-maximal ideals. Isn’t there some other terminology?

@ZhenLin This is the standard notation as far as I know, e.g., https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00AR or 4.3.7 of https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGaug2922public.pdf, or in Hartshorne, etc.

@DrewHeard: Did you actually mean the tag to be at.algebraic-topology or maybe ag.algebraic-geometry?

@M.G. I did intentionally do algebraic-topology. This is of course not strictly speaking a question about algebraic topology, but these type of questions originated in this field, and many topologists (including myself) have thought a lot about these types of problems.

Do you know whether it generates when $R=k[t^{1/p^\infty}]$ for some algebraically closed field $k$ of char $p$? The map $k[t]\to R$ induces a homeomorphism of Zariski spectra, so this seems to be somehow perpendicular to the examples that you want?

@Z.M. No, I don't know the answer in this example.
